# convert array of objects to yearly and monthly using javascript reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

**Problem Statement :**

I have an array of objects with month , sales & orders as attributes. now, I want to create a function like following. which can provide result based on the argument.

```
function aggregate(json_data , yearly)
{
  // This function could return an array of objects like following
  // [ { Month : 2014 , Sales : x , Amount : x},
  //   { Month : 2015 , Sales : x , Amount : x }
  //  ]
};
```

If the user pass argument as quarter , then data should aggregate quarterly

```
function aggregate(json_data , quarterly)
{
  // This function could return an array of objects
  // [ { Month : 2014Q1 , Sales : x , Amount : x},
  //   { Month : 2014Q2 , Sales : x , Amount : x }
  //    ............
  //    ............
  //  ]
}
```

**Sample Data**

```
 var data = [
  {
     Month: 201401,
     Sales: 15,
     Orders: 4
  },
  {
     Month: 201402,
     Sales: 12,
     Orders: 3

  },
  {
     Month: 201403,
     Sales  : 16,
     Orders: 5

  },
  {
     Month: 201404,
     Sales: 12,
     Orders: 2
  },

  {
     Month: 201405,
     Sales: 12,
     Orders: 4
  },

  {
     Month: 201406,
     Sales: 10,
     Orders: 3
  },

  {
     Month: 201407,
     Sales: 15,
     Orders: 2
  },

  {
     Month: 201408,
     Sales: 14,
     Orders: 3
  },

  {
     Month: 201409,
     Sales: 13,
     Orders: 6
  },

  {
     Month: 201410,
     Sales: 13,
     Orders: 5
  },

  {
     Month: 201411,
     Sales: 12,
     Orders: 2
  },

  {
     Month: 201412,
     Sales: 11,
     Orders: 4
  },
  {
     Month: 201501,
     Sales: 15,
     Orders: 4
  },
  {
     Month: 201502,
     Sales: 12,
     Orders: 6

  },
  {
     Month: 201503,
     Sales  : 6,
     Orders: 5

  },
  {
     Month: 201504,
     Sales: 10,
     Orders: 11
  },

  {
     Month: 201505,
     Sales: 10,
     Orders: 2
  },

  {
     Month: 201506,
     Sales: 10,
     Orders: 3
  },

  {
     Month: 201507,
     Sales: 10,
     Orders: 1
  },

  {
     Month: 201508,
     Sales: 10,
     Orders: 4
  },

  {
     Month: 201509,
     Sales: 10,
     Orders: 2
  },

  {
     Month: 201510,
     Sales: 10,
     Orders: 3
  },

  {
     Month: 201511,
     Sales: 10,
     Orders: 2
  },

  {
     Month: 201512,
     Sales: 10,
     Orders: 1
  }
];
```

Please advice, If there is any other suggestions either to adapt the question.

*Someone has suggested that it is a duplicated question. However, I am working with date object. ( Please check the duplicate link before suggesting)*

Comment: What is `yearly` and `quarterly`? Why do you need it to be a single function not 2 separate functions `aggregateYearly` and `aggregateQuarterly`? And have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: Other than writing the problem statement, you haven't put any effort into researching or attempting a possible solution for what you're trying to do. While that is not officially required by Stack Overflow, it is heavily encouraged, since it reduces the likelihood for duplicate questions and low quality content.

Comment: Speaking of which, this is a possible duplicate of [In an array of objects, how can I aggregate based on object property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441272/in-an-array-of-objects-how-can-i-aggregate-based-on-object-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table and use a key based on the wanted yearly or quarterly aggregation of the data.

This proposal uses `Month` as string.

```js
function aggregate(array, quarterly) {
    var hash = Object.create(null),
        result = [];

    data.forEach(function (o) {
        var [period, month] = o.Month.toString().split(/(?=..$)/);

        if (quarterly) {
            period += 'Q' + Math.floor((+month + 2) / 3);
        }
        if (!hash[period]) {
            hash[period] = { period, Sales: 0, Orders: 0 };
            result.push(hash[period]);
        }
        hash[period].Sales += o.Sales;
        hash[period].Orders += o.Orders;
    });

    return result;
}

var data = [{ Month: 201401, Sales: 15, Orders: 4 }, { Month: 201402, Sales: 12, Orders: 3 }, { Month: 201403, Sales: 16, Orders: 5 }, { Month: 201404, Sales: 12, Orders: 2 }, { Month: 201405, Sales: 12, Orders: 4 }, { Month: 201406, Sales: 10, Orders: 3 }, { Month: 201407, Sales: 15, Orders: 2 }, { Month: 201408, Sales: 14, Orders: 3 }, { Month: 201409, Sales: 13, Orders: 6 }, { Month: 201410, Sales: 13, Orders: 5 }, { Month: 201411, Sales: 12, Orders: 2 }, { Month: 201412, Sales: 11, Orders: 4 }, { Month: 201501, Sales: 15, Orders: 4 }, { Month: 201502, Sales: 12, Orders: 6 }, { Month: 201503, Sales: 6, Orders: 5 }, { Month: 201504, Sales: 10, Orders: 11 }, { Month: 201505, Sales: 10, Orders: 2 }, { Month: 201506, Sales: 10, Orders: 3 }, { Month: 201507, Sales: 10, Orders: 1 }, { Month: 201508, Sales: 10, Orders: 4 }, { Month: 201509, Sales: 10, Orders: 2 }, { Month: 201510, Sales: 10, Orders: 3 }, { Month: 201511, Sales: 10, Orders: 2 }, { Month: 201512, Sales: 10, Orders: 1 }];

console.log(aggregate(data));
console.log(aggregate(data, true));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if it's the same problem, but I recently had to solve what seems, at least, a very similar problem. I had an array of objects with a date and a value, such as this:

```
statsData = [
      { x: randomDate, y: 1 },
      { x: randomDate, y: 2 },
      { x: randomDate, y: 1 },
      { x: randomDate, y: 4 },
      { x: randomDate, y: 3 },
      { x: randomDate, y: 2 },
      { x: randomDate, y: 1 },
      { x: randomDate, y: 4 },
      { x: randomDate, y: 6 },
      { x: randomDate, y: 5 },
      { x: randomDate, y: 1 }
]
```

And I needed to reduce it, so that all the objects with the same month are grouped together under one object that adds all the values of that month.

What I did was, first to sort them, in case they don't come chronollogically ordered:

```
sortData(data) {
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      return +a.x - +b.x;
    });
}
```

And then use this reduce function:

```
reduceByMonth(data) {
    if (data) {
      return data.reduce((total, current, index) => {
        const month = { x: null, y: 0 };
        if (index !== 0 && (total && total[total.length - 1] && total[total.length - 1].x && monthsMatch(total[total.length - 1].x, current.x))) {
          total[total.length - 1].y = total[total.length - 1].y + current.y;
          return total;
        } else {
          month.x = new Date(current.x.getFullYear(), current.x.getMonth());
          month.y = month.y + current.y;
          total.push(month);
          return total;
        }
      }, []);
    } else {
      console.error('Cannot reduce undefined data');
      return []
    }
  }
```

the function monthsMatch is simply checking if the months of two dates match:

```
monthsMatch(dateA, dateB) {
    if (dateA.getFullYear() === dateB.getFullYear()) {
      return dateA.getMonth() === dateB.getMonth();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```